# django Apache httpd.conf Setup

Tags: django, apache, wamp, httpd.conf

### Context:

- WampServer 2.2 64 bit (Edit: I believe I actually had the 32 bit version)
- Apache 2.2.22
- mod_wsgi 3.4 64bit: [courtesy of this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi)
- Python 3.3.2 64 bit
- django 1.5.1

The `python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"` test works perfectly so I know django is installed correctly.

I have added the LoadModule line in httpd.conf to load mod_wsgi.so file and the server restarts with no problems.

Update: Running the startup project on the development server works.

I am trying to get through [tutorial #1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) and get the startupproject demo up and running. As suggested by the tutorial I put my code outside the document root in a folder called `www-src` (got a better name?). The DocumentRoot of my wampserver is `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"`.

The file structure is as follows:

```
|- C:
    |- wamp
        |- www (DocumentRoot)
        |- www-src
            |- first_django_site
                |- first_django_site
                |   |- __pycache__
                |   |   |- __init__.cpython-33.pyc
                |   |   |- settings.cpython-33.pyc
                |   |   |- urls.cpython-33.pyc
                |   |   |- wsgi.cpython-33.pyc
                |   |- __init__.py
                |   |- settings.py
                |   |- urls.py
                |   |- wsgi.py
                |- first_django_site.conf
                |- manage.py
```

I want the url to be `localhost/first-django-site` in order to separate it from the normal php www projects already in wamp.

What is the way to write paths to access stuff outside the document root? I am not sure if "../" works.

Here are the multiple methods I have tried to write the appropriate apache httpd.conf. What is the best method and correct way to do this?

**Block 1:**

```
WSGIScriptAlias /first-django-site "../www-src/first_django_site/first_django_site/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "../www-src/first_django_site"

<Directory "../www-src/first_django_site/first_django_site">
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Block 2:**

```
Alias /www-src-alias/ "c:/wamp/www-src/"

<Directory "c:/wamp/www-src/">
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# alias is way above in the <Ifmodule> so redacted

WSGIScriptAlias /first-django-site "/www-src-alias/first_django_site/first_django_site/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "/www-src-alias/first_django_site"

<Directory "/www-src-alias/first_django_site/first_django_site">
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Block 3:**

```
Include "../www-src/first_django_site/first_django_site.conf"
```

first_django_site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    #ServerAlias www.mysite.com

    WSGIScriptAlias /first-django-site "../www-src/first_django_site/first_django_site/wsgi.py"
    WSGIPythonPath "../www-src/first_django_site"

    <Directory "../www-src/first_django_site/first_django_site">
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Block 4:** This gives a 500 internal server error.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /first-django-site "C:/wamp/www-src/first_django_site/first_django_site/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/wamp/www-src/first_django_site"

<Directory "C:/wamp/www-src/first_django_site/first_django_site">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Why are you not using the development server?

Comment: @dan-klasson I want some practice setting it up on Apache.

Comment: I would start by using absolute paths instead of relative.

Comment: @dan-klasson See block 4 (just added). Gives a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Check your Apache error log then to see what the error is.

Comment: @dan-klasson good call. Critical error "configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /first-django-site" - looking for solutions atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had assumed I was using the 64 bit version of WAMP but although I am still unsure if I am using 32 or 64 bit WAMP, I have concluded I am using 32 bit.

I used the 32 bit version mod_wsgi.so, restarted the server and it worked.

I used this block of code to run the server (below) and I can access it from: `http://localhost/first-django-site`

```
WSGIScriptAlias /first-django-site "C:/wamp/www-src/first_django_site/first_django_site/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/wamp/www-src/first_django_site/"

<Directory "C:/wamp/www-src/first_django_site/first_django_site/">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

I have also downloaded the new WampServer 2.4 64 bit and have also successfully set up the django startproject with the mod_wsgi.so 64 bit.